# Grouping values in a list and convert the output into JSON using C#

Tags: c#, json, linq, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am have an list of object. Which has 4 properties.    `Month, Category, 2015 & 2014`

```
 Month  Category    2015    2014
    Jan A   10  100
    Jan B   20  200
    Jan C   30  300
    Jan D   40  400
    Feb B   50  500
    Feb C   60  600
    Feb D   70  700
    Mar A   80  800
    Mar I   90  900
    Mar J   100 1000
```

I want to group the values using month and I want to generate JSON output like this. I am creating property in JSON object by prefixing `cur` & `pre` keywords to category name & the value they represents comes from `2014 and 2015` years

```
[{  
    name: "jan",
    curA: 10,
    preA: 100,
    curB: 20,
    preB: 200,
    curC: 30,
    preC: 400,
    curD: 40,
    preD: 400
}, {    
    name: "feb",
    curB: 50,
    preB: 500,
    curC: 60,
    preC: 600,
    curD: 70,
    preD: 700
}, {    
    name: "mat",
    curA: 80,
    preA: 800,
    curI: 90,
    preI: 900,
    curJ: 100,
    preJ: 1000
}]
```

I can use JSON.NET to serialize C# object into JSON but I am struggling to create a class which can be converted into required format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array of dictionaries.

```
var list = new List<Dictionary<string, int>> ();
```

You'll have to figure out how you want to populate your dictionaries based on the data but you'll need to do this for as many months / segmentation points that you wish:

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
     { "name", 10 },
     { "curA", 100 },
     { "preA", 20 } // And so on...
};
list.Add(data);
```

And then you can convert your list to json in a similar manner:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(points, Formatting.Indented);
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**: Original question was asking for help converting his source list into the desired list in the JSON string.

Without knowing the format of your source list (objects, datarows, etc) I made an assumption that you just have a list of objects. My object look like this:

```
public class ListRow {
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string _2015 { get; set; }
    public string _2014 { get; set; }
}
```

I'm also assuming you have a variable called `list` which contains a list of those objects. An unpopulated definition looks like:

```
var list = new List<ListRow> ();
```

I quickly put this untested code together as a guide on how you could go about converting your source list into the new format.

```
    var convertedList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>> ();
    var groupedList = list.GroupBy (_ => _.Month);
    foreach (var item in groupedList) {
        var data = new Dictionary<string, string> ();
        data.Add ("name", item.Key);
        foreach (var value in item) {
            data.Add (string.Format ("cur{0}", value.Category), value._2015);
            data.Add (string.Format ("pre{0}", value.Category), value._2014);
        }
        convertedList.Add (data);
    }
```

And then you'll want to serialize the `convertedList` variable.

Hope this gets you closer to your solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but i dont see how this will scale well as the values grows. This looks more like manually reading all the values and getting the desired result. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: No, I specifically wrote that you'd have to figure out how to populate your dictionaries based on the data. I gave you an example that would give you the json you want...but I am not familiar with your data or how you are transforming it from the list to the desired properties.

Comment: Was your question to give an example of how you can output your data in proper json, or did you want help figuring out how to do the data conversion? I answered the former.

Comment: In my question I have specified the data I have, the format its available in (List of object, each object for 4 property). I want to convert the value into json and I also want create new properties by adding some predefined text and using existing property. I need to ensure as the no of object grows, same code is able to generate required output ,

Comment: Gotcha, that's a little more clear. Give me a few minutes to write something up.

Comment: Is it possible to get the same output if my class looks like this `Year, Category, Month, Value`. Example of data `2014   A    Jan     100   `  &  `2015   A    Jan     10 `. What I am saying is instead of having two columns for current year and previous year, I will only have 1 column called year and years will be added as row

Comment: You can but you'd have to adjust your logic a bit and may need to nest a GroupBy. If you need to do this and are struggling feel free to send me a message and I'll see if I can't guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my implementation :

```
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{

    public class Transactions
    {
        public string Month { get; set; }
        public string Cath { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public int Unit { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var transactionsList = new List<Transactions>();
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "A", Year = "pre", Unit = 10 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "A", Year = "cur", Unit = 100 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "B", Year = "pre", Unit = 20 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "B", Year = "cur", Unit = 200 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "C", Year = "pre", Unit = 30 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "C", Year = "cur", Unit = 300 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "D", Year = "pre", Unit = 40 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "D", Year = "cur", Unit = 400 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Feb", Cath = "B", Year = "pre", Unit = 50 });
            transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Feb", Cath = "B", Year = "cur", Unit = 500 });


            var transactionsQuery =
                (from t in transactionsList
                group t by t.Month into newGroup
                orderby newGroup.Key descending
                select newGroup).ToList();


            var dictionaryList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

            foreach (var nameGroup in transactionsQuery)
            {
                var data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                data.Add("name", nameGroup.Key);

                foreach (var item in nameGroup)
                {                   
                    data.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}", item.Year, item.Cath), item.Unit);
                }
                dictionaryList.Add(data);

            }

           var ser = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionaryList);

            Console.WriteLine(ser);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the same output if my class looks like this `Year, Category, Month, Value`. Example of data` 2014 A Jan 100`  & `2015 A Jan 10` . What I am saying is instead of having two columns for current year and previous year, I will only have 1 column called year and years will be added as row. If the data format changes how can I get the same output ?

Comment: instead of transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Month = "Jan", Cath = "A", Year = "pre", Unit = 10 }); put  transactionsList.Add(new Transactions() { Year = "2014", Cath = "A", Month = "Jan", Unit = 100 });  and just replace your 2014 by 'pre'